# What if we run commands like `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/hda` on virtual machine?

Tags: command-line

What if we run commands like `rm -rf /` or `mv / /dev/null` or `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/hda` on the virtual machine? Will it affect the host machine? Or what the results of running these commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtualization provides a relatively strong separation between the virtual machine and the host. This is provided by kernel features backed up by CPU features. The recent "Spectre" CPU flaw is particularly concerning because it potentially provides a way for attackers to break down some of this separation — but that doesn't change what happens with "normal" operations in the guest.

The virtual machine presents the operating system with a virtual disk — a "fake" block device constructed from underlying storage. Short of a bug in the virtualization itself, nothing you do to the virtual disk will "break out" and affect other parts of the underlying storage, or the underlying OS.

From the point of view of the host, the virtual machine is just a process like any other program, and operations on the underlying storage done by that thread are constrained just like any other program. If the guest (the virtual machine) is very busy, it can cause the CPU to heat up and the fans will come on and etc., just like with any other busy program. Writing to disk in the guest is the same — it causes IO operations, and many busy VMs can get in a conflict for resources. (This is often the cause for high load on what seems to be an idle machine.)

From the point of view of the guest, the example commands you give would execute just as you'd expect them to on a physical machine. They will render the guest OS inoperable. But back to the host machine — they're nothing special. You'll just have a VM disk image that you need to restore from backup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is that mean it will affect the part of underlying storage used to simulate the virtual storage? And will 'dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/port' will affect the host machine's I/O cause the incoming logical disk I/O requests will be translated to the physical I/O requests?

Comment: @Hang With respect to the host machine, that operation, when carried out on the guest machine (VM) is safe. It will trigger I/O operations on the host machine but so will all other disk-related operations on the guest. The data of the guest's `hda` is a file on the host. That file behaves like any other file on the host.

Comment: The guest device isn't necessarily a file. It *could* also be an iscsi share or an lvm volume or even a "physical" block device.

Answer (score 0):

By default Virtual disk on the Virtual machine don't occupy all its volume on the physical machine (only files that exist except free spaces). After those operations it will.